# Visualize Gensim Word2vec Embeddings in Tensorboard Projector

Tags: python, tensorflow, gensim, tensorboard, word-embedding

I've only seen a few questions that ask this, and none of them have an answer yet, so I thought I might as well try. I've been using gensim's word2vec model to create some vectors. I exported them into text, and tried importing it on tensorflow's live model of the embedding projector. One problem. *It didn't work*. It told me that the tensors were improperly formatted. So, being a beginner, I thought I would ask some people with more experience about possible solutions.
Equivalent to my code:

```
import gensim
corpus = [["words","in","sentence","one"],["words","in","sentence","two"]]
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(iter = 5,size = 64)
model.build_vocab(corpus)
# save memory
vectors = model.wv
del model
vectors.save_word2vec_format("vect.txt",binary = False)
```

That creates the model, saves the vectors, and then prints the results out nice and pretty in a tab delimited file with values for all of the dimensions. I understand how to do what I'm doing, I just can't figure out what's wrong with the way I put it in tensorflow, as the documentation regarding that is pretty scarce as far as I can tell.
One idea that has been presented to me is implementing the appropriate tensorflow code, but I don’t know how to code that, just import files in the live demo.

Edit: I have a new problem now. The object I have my vectors in is non-iterable because gensim apparently decided to make its own data structures that are non-compatible with what I'm trying to do.
  Ok. Done with that too! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would it be possible to add the tensorflow part of the code? Thanks

Comment: Not sure. Never tried, and besides, I can’t figure out how to create an embedding projector visualization using tensorflow. Although I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you are describing is possible. What you have to keep in mind is that Tensorboard reads from saved tensorflow binaries which represent your variables on disk.

> More information on saving and restoring tensorflow graph and variables [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model)

**The main task is therefore to get the embeddings as saved tf variables.**

> Assumptions:
>
> - in the following code `embeddings` is a python dict `{word:np.array (np.shape==[embedding_size])}`
> - python version is 3.5+
> - used libraries are `numpy as np`, `tensorflow as tf`
> - the directory to store the tf variables is `model_dir/`

---

## Step 1: Stack the embeddings to get a single `np.array`

```
embeddings_vectors = np.stack(list(embeddings.values(), axis=0))
# shape [n_words, embedding_size]
```

---

## Step 2: Save the `tf.Variable` on disk

```
# Create some variables.
emb = tf.Variable(embeddings_vectors, name='word_embeddings')

# Add an op to initialize the variable.
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Later, launch the model, initialize the variables and save the
# variables to disk.
with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(init_op)

# Save the variables to disk.
   save_path = saver.save(sess, "model_dir/model.ckpt")
   print("Model saved in path: %s" % save_path)
```

> `model_dir` should contain files `checkpoint`, `model.ckpt-1.data-00000-of-00001`, `model.ckpt-1.index`, `model.ckpt-1.meta`

---

## Step 3: Generate a `metadata.tsv`

To have a beautiful labeled cloud of embeddings, you can provide tensorboard with metadata as Tab-Separated Values (tsv) (*cf.* [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/get_started/embedding_viz#metadata)).

```
words = '\n'.join(list(embeddings.keys()))

with open(os.path.join('model_dir', 'metadata.tsv'), 'w') as f:
   f.write(words)

# .tsv file written in model_dir/metadata.tsv
```

---

## Step 4: Visualize

Run `$ tensorboard --logdir model_dir` -> **Projector**.

To load metadata, the magic happens here:

[image: load_meta]

---

As a reminder, some *word2vec* embedding projections are also available on http://projector.tensorflow.org/

Comment: Thanks! Will try when I get back on my PC!

Comment: Actually I do have a question. Does this method require column headers on all the features?

Comment: No it does not, all you need to feed is the stacked tensor of embeddings

Comment: I meant the .tsv, but I suppose that also answers that question in a way.

Comment: There's a typo in your solution. Step 1 should be `embeddings_vectors = np.stack(list(embeddings.values()), axis=0)` or otherwise it won't run ( there will be syntax error due to a missing ")" ).

Comment: Don't forget to add the `encoding="utf-8"` when you write the 'metadata.tsv', otherwise you may get errors depending on the characters you have, so it should be: `with open(os.path.join('model_dir', 'metadata.tsv'), 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:`

Comment: Thank you for posting all those steps to answer this post. I have a question about 'the directory to store the tf variables is model_dir/'. I am very new to this so I am not sure how to set up a directory to meet this requirement. Do you mind elaborating more on that?

Comment: @Vicky any directory can be used. I just chose to name it `model_dir` for the sake of example. You will see how `model_dir` is referenced in the different steps. If you do not like the name of it, feel free to change all references to `model_dir` to what suits you best

Answer (score 3):

Gensim actually has the official way to do this.

[Documentation about it](https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/gensim-3.2.0/autoapi/scripts/word2vec2tensor/index.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. However, the metadata file it creates is basically just the vocabulary. In my case, I wanted to a few covariates (movie genres in the movie lens dataset). So I ended up reading it's metadata.tsv and adding my own columns to it, before loading it into tensorboard.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you!

Comment: Marco, can you add an example? the documentation host works like windows 3.11 (year 1993)

Comment: Sorry. Are you able to reproduce the documentation Gonzalo?

Answer (score 0):

The above answers didn't work for me. What I found out pretty useful was this script (will be added to gensim in the future) [Source](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1035)

To transform the data to metadata:

```py
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format(model_path, binary=True)
with open( tensorsfp, 'w+') as tensors:
    with open( metadatafp, 'w+') as metadata:
         for word in model.index2word:
           encoded=word.encode('utf-8')
           metadata.write(encoded + '\n')
           vector_row = '\t'.join(map(str, model[word]))
           tensors.write(vector_row + '\n')
```

Or follow this [gist](https://gist.github.com/lampts/026a4d6400b1efac9a13a3296f16e655)

Answer (score 0):

the gemsim provide convert method word2vec to tf projector file

```py
python -m gensim.scripts.word2vec2tensor -i ~w2v_model_file -o output_folder
```

add in projector wesite, upload the metadata
[image]